# Translation working but only after page resresh

Tags: angular, translation

My ts code:

```
isEditing = '';
ngOnInit () {
this.isEditing = this.translateService.instant('OneWord.Add');
}
```

My html:

```
<button> {{isEditing}} </button>
```

Translation service is working but only when user refresh page. With html file everything is translated right after changing language. How do I make this act the same?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what you're doing. There are multiple ways for handling i18n and you don't even say which one you're using. Please, prepare a minimal  reproduction of your issue on stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the translation in html file too.

```
<span [translate]="'OneWord.Add'"></span>
```

or you can use the following if you need to pass a string to a component

```
<app-mycustomcomponent title="{{'OneWord.Add' | translate}}"></app-mycustomcomponent>
```

or if you work with observables:

```
isEditing: Observable<string>;
ngOnInit () {
    this.isEditing = this.translateService.get('OneWord.Add');
}

<span>{{isEditing | async}}</span>
```

Be aware of the documentation of `instant`: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods

Comment: I've added more code, I've tried with observable but it's not working well. I've got [object Object] on button

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnInit()` is only called when the component is initially created. You can listen for updates as follows:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
    this.isEditing = this.translateService.instant('OneWord.Add');
  });
}
```

Comment: Working but only after I change language, before that I've got empty button

Comment: If i refresh the page I've got also empty button

Comment: Then you can make use of rxjs's [startWith](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) to trigger it initally.

`this.translateService.onLangChange.pipe(startWith(undefined)).subscribe[...]`

Or you can just copy the `this.isEditing = [...]` line, but then you have to remember to update it both places.

But if you can, I would translate it in the html.